# Search engine PHP return error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("database360");
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Search Engine</title>
</head>

<body>

<center>
<h1 style="color:#069; font-size:36px;">TEST ENGINEenter code here</h1>

<form action="./result.php" method="get">
        <input type="text" name="input" size="50" <?php echo $_GET['input']; ?> />
        <input type="submit" value="search"/>
</form>
</center>

<hr/>

<?php 

$input = $_GET['input'];
$terms = explode(" ", $input);
$query = "SELECT * FROM search WHERE";

foreach ($terms as $each){
    $i++;
    if ($i == 1)
       $query .= "keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
    else
       $query .= "OR keywords LIKE '%each%' ";
}

//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("database360");
$query1 = mysql_query($query);
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query1);
if ($numrows > 0){
    while ($rows=mysqlfetch_assoc($query1)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $keywords = $row['keyword'];
        $link = $row['link'];

        echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</h2>
        $description<br></br>";

    }

}
else echo "No results found for \"<b>$input</b>\"";
//disconnect
mysql_close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

error message are :

> Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEARCH\result.php on
>   line 33
>
> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEARCH\result.php on line 46 No results found
>   for "Contact"

Comment: Put `$i = 0;` before the foreach loop. Also, note that you wrote `each` (a string) instead of `$each` (a variable). Your query is also vulnerable. The query error is likely no space between `WHERE` and `keywords` (try printing the query and see)

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqlfetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEARCH\result.php on line 51

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 33 you have `$i++`, but you haven't initialised `$i`

I expect you have a syntax error in your MySQL query. Try this:

```
$query1 = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

which will display the SQL error which you'll have to fix.

More: Your SQL is susceptible to an injection attack. Make sure you escape your inputs properly, and don't use `mysql()` - it''s deprecated. Use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Comment: after correct the syntax....Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqlfetch_assoc() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SEARCH\result.php on line 51

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc()`

Comment: Thanks alot x100000000